# percona timestamp default 0 not null

Tags: mysql, laravel, percona

I have used Brew to install percona-server on my mac for local development

```
┌─(veilig@Jamies-MacBook-Air:s018)──────────────(~/api.foo.com)─┐
└─(13:25:%)── brew info percona-server                                                      ──(Wed,Sep03 - feature/users)─┘
percona-server: stable 5.6.19-67.0 (bottled)
```

I'm trying to run this query

```
create table `courses` (
   `id` varchar(36) not null,
   `title` varchar(255) not null,
   `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null,
   `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null,
   `tokens` int not null default '0',
   `product_id` int null,
   `track_id` varchar(36) not null
) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

and its choking when it has to create the `updated_at` column because `timestamp default 0`.  The sql stmt is being created from within my Laravel 4.2 PHP application.

**Is there a way to relax these restrictions to make this work?**

This is the exact error

```
veilig@localhost (api_foo_com) > create table `courses` (`id` varchar(36) not null, `title` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `tokens` int not null default '0', `product_id` int null, `track_id` varchar(36) not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

When we try this on my coworkers database, we don't encounter this issue.  He's running:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

Comment: You are using the schema builder to come up with this?

Comment: Yes I am....but I found I had two SQL modes set for MySql: NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE. When I remove these modes, everything works as expected.

Comment: Removing `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` solved this for me too. You should answer your own question with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to remove two `sql-mode` from my `/etc/my.cnf` (or wherever your MySQL config is located) to allow the laravel migrations to correctly work.

`NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`